# How can I dynamically create buttons with the data of an API in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I started to create buttons and grids with given data. For that purpose I created an array with objects in it. With the data in the array I create button and grids dynamically but now I want to do the same but instead of using a local variable to build the grids I want to create them with given data by an API. My problem is that it return an Observable and not an array. I tried to transform the data and push it into an array but I get always errors.

I tried to use the take and tap operator but everything is crashing always. I cannot transform the data as I want such that it works again.

In app.component.ts

```
// I have to change this.gridService.items somehow that it fits with an API
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gridItems = this.gridService.items;
  }
```

In grid.service.ts the private variable _items should be replaced with an API-Call which returns the same data structure and content but it would be an Observable -- and there is where to problem begins...

Can anyone edit my project with some dummy code how it could possibly work, so I understand the logic?

I really would appreciate your help.

If any information is missing, please tell me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara! Thank you for the question. If I understood you correctly, you want to replace your `this.gridItems = this.gridService.items;` to the HTTP call.

I've prepared a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-njqbns) example with emulation of an API call.

My main idea is the usage of `$async` pipe with `Observable<GridItem[]>` instead of sync getting.
Don't forget to handle errors from an API.

P.S. I'm waiting for your feedback.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement it that way! If I have any question left, I hope I can ask you :)

Comment: Of course! I'm waiting for your questions. Good luck :)

Comment: Hello again :-), I would like to ask you something if you would not mind. If I have another property in the ```grid.model.ts file``` in your project like id, how would I only access the property ```sBezeichnung``` in the ```grid.component.html``` when in my ```grid.component.ts``` the code changes to  ```this.grid.map((line) => {
      matrix[line.nZeile - 1][line.nSpalte - 1] = [line.sBezeichnung, line.ID];}``` , so an Array of properties for one field - but I do only want to show one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use async pipe on your observable result:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">{{ item | json }}</div>
```

`$` on end of variable is convention for variable containing streamed data in case of angular observables.